# Instantiate keeps repeating itself on trigger which deletes itself upon collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, instantiation

I have been trying to make an infinite colour switch game replica in C#. 
My plan is to have a green point inside the spinning circle. Upon collision with the player this would give the user a score and delete the green circle. As well as activate a trigger to spawn a new circle that is 14 higher in the y value than the current location of the consumed dot. The start would always have 2 circles already there therefore as you move up you do not see the new circles form as it spawns in the 2nd one ahead. 
There is a destroy block that deletes all blocks outside of the players vision downwards to reduce lag as old circles would build up or to restart the game when the player dies.
The problem is there are multiple circles created in the same position as seen by the debug of CurrentSpawnPoint which remains the same for multiple spawns or the height which seems to increase rapidly as if it was multiplying or just adding really quickly. 
I am just a beginner in unity and still do not know all of the C# variables and surely there is a simple solution to my problem. Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time.
    Here is a GitHub link to the actual game file if my description is still unclear. https://github.com/Xotsu/Color-Switch-replica

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

  public float jumpForce = 7f; 
  public Rigidbody2D rb;
  public SpriteRenderer sr;
  public string currentColor;
  public GameObject Green;
  public GameObject[] obj;
  public float SpawnAmount = 1f;
  public Color ColorBlue;
  public Color ColorPurple;
  public Color ColorYellow;
  public Color ColorPink;
  public int Score = 0;
  public int Height = 0;
  Vector3 CurrentSpawnPoint;

  private void Start()
  {
    SetRandomColor();
  }

  void Update() 
  {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
      rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
  {
    if (col.tag == "Change")
    {
      SetRandomColor();
      Destroy(col.gameObject);
      return;
    }
    else if (col.tag == "Point")
    {
      Debug.Log("Point gained");
      Destroy(col.gameObject);
      Score += 1;
      Height += 7;
      CurrentSpawnPoint = col.transform.position;
      CurrentSpawnPoint.y += 7;
      Instantiate(Green, CurrentSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
      Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], CurrentSpawnPoint,  Quaternion.identity);

      Debug.Log(Height);
      Debug.Log(CurrentSpawnPoint);
      return;
    }
    else if (col.tag != currentColor)
    {
      Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
      SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
  }

  void SetRandomColor()
  {
    int index = Random.Range(0, 4);
    switch (index)
    {
      case 0:
        currentColor = "Blue";
        sr.color = ColorBlue;
        break;
     case 1:
        currentColor = "Yellow";
        sr.color = ColorYellow;
        break;
     case 2:
        currentColor = "Purple";
        sr.color = ColorPurple;
        break;
     case 3:
        currentColor = "Pink";
        sr.color = ColorPink;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide an image so that I can fully understand what you are trying to do..

Comment: Would it help that instead of deleting the green dot and creating another, would it be easier to just give the player a point and move it upwards? That avoids any instantiation problems, at least in the short term.

Comment: @pseudoabdul I delete the current point to avoid repetition of instantiation. The whole point of creating a new green dot is that it creates a new circle along with it therefore moving the dot would just move the circle therefore removing the randomness of the game.

Comment: @Ginxxx I have added the game to GitHub where you can download it and see the problem yourself (there are multiple circles that spawn on the same point when they shouldn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was spawning in the green dot independently along with the one in the circle prefab which made duplicates. Sorry for the stupid question :/